# How to save output in console display to a text file in Java?

Tags: java, console, text-files

I have tried to save output of application to text file with the code below.
It can write output to the text file but the output didn't show in the console display.
How can I do to the output both display on console and save to file?

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class DocGhiFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            final boolean append = true, autoflush = true;
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("test.txt", append), autoflush);
            System.setOut(printStream);
            System.setErr(printStream);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error during reading/writing");
        }
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }
}
```

Console display and text file after code running:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use two print stream, one to write to console and another to file as below

```
        try {
            final boolean append = true, autoflush = true;
            PrintStream printWriter = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("test.txt", append), autoflush);
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(System.out, autoflush); // to write to console
            System.setOut(printWriter);
            printStream.println("Test to console");
            System.setErr(printWriter);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error during reading/writing");
        }
        System.out.println("TEST to file");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I think it not good in case of a lot of output :(

Comment: did this solve your problem, if yes please accept answer and hit upVote

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run your `Java Program` in `command prompt` just to `save` your `Program Output` Or `Console Output`!

`java` `Programfile` `|` (Pipe) `clipboard` : will save your Program Output to the Clipboard.

`java` `Programfile` `>` `Sourcefile` will write your Program Output to the Source file.

`java` `Programfile` `>>` `Sourcefile` will append your Program Output to the Source file.